# Setting up MVC app on a server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one dll containing my entire mvc app running on iis7 server. Should I instead have compiled controllers and business logic into separate dll's? Furthermore, should I install the non controller dll's in a separate server and if so do I configure a new virtual directory to the remote server?

What is the typical practice here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess that depends on your business needs, but in general I am a fan of modularity.  We have our Model shared between multiple sites so it is in its own DLL and the controllers etc. for each site are generally in another (for each site) and additional add-ons in their own as well.

Compiling into one DLL would probably get you a performance increase, but you would be hurt when it comes to upgrading individual modules.